# what will happen if int concatenate with string in php?

Tags: php, string, int, concatenation

```
$a = int 20;
$b = "ABCD";
$c = $b.$a;
```

1)What will be the data type of `$c`?

2)Is it necessary to use **strval()** before concatenate?

Comment: Can't you try from yourself ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is wrong

```
$a = int 20;
```

It should be

```
$a = 20;
```

If you are typecasting, then it should be

```
$a = (int)20;
```

It will be string if you concatenate it. Even you try this

```
$a = 20;
$b = 60;
echo $b.$a;
```

It will give

```
6020
```

not `80`.

Answer (score 0):

Please do try [research](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) before asking question.

1. `$c == $b.$a == ABCD20` ($c will be String)
2. **NOT** necessary